# Why are questions based on misunderstanding about a tool closed as "no longer reproducible"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I fail to understand why this question is closed as "no longer reproducible" and now deleted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63980654 ([link for users who don't have 10k reputation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhJhY.png)) Yes, it is based on a misunderstanding on the tool I'm using, but surely it's reproducible?

An answer that explains why it's a feature and not a bug is what I'm looking for. Probably there are other people have the same question, and keeping it open means that more people can be helped.

In my understanding no longer reproducible questions are mysterious bugs that OP has but others don't, yet no one can suggest what to check. Am I correct?

The explanation in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) doesn't get me any further:

> Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

The fact that this notice suggests to provide the minimum reproducible example suggests that this close reason is for mysterious bugs I think.

So why should it be closed, and why should it be the same with other "no longer reproducible" questions?

[image]

Comment: Consider: People cannot reproduce using a regex repetition in a function that does not accept regex repetitions. It looks like regex repetition but it is not.

Comment: You wrote "Why doesn't it become this?" in the question. I guess you could have written a bit more why you expected this certain output.

Comment: This (meta) question sets aside the point that the (original) question is about how to use a piece of software, so would be better suited to [su].

Comment: FWIW - we used to have different close reasons. As each one was taken away, users have reverted to the next most applicable one. It sounds like the ideal one here that would have been used in the past would be 'lacks minimal understanding'.

Comment: @TylerH what happened to that reason? What is the suggestion when it was applied?

Comment: @Ooker I don't recall; it's probably documented somewhere here on Meta. But my guess would be "it was used less than judiciously" aka people used it for things they thought askers *should* know even if the asker tried to learn it already. Stack Overflow also used to be much more about experts/professionals but now it is much more for the everyman programmer. The company owners now wouldn't want to see the hit to new question metrics that would happen if we started applying that reason again.

Comment: The thing is, @TylerH, that Stack Overflow was always supposed to be for everyone. "How do I move the turtle in Logo?" is not a new question. OP's problem here is the cadre of deletionists, who look for excuses to delete stuff.

Comment: @Ooker , the simple fact is **folks don't care much about the *specific* close reason**.  When someone sees a low quality question, they just click to close it.  (Very often they literally just choose the top one in the list!  Who can be bothered tediously and carefully evaluating a list of close reasons, few people.)  That's the actual answer to your question.  Any rationales given supposedly explaining the exquisite details of why one or the other were chosen, are totally fatuous.

Comment: @TRiG Eh, it's probably true Joel/Jeff didn't intend to gatekeep, but I think the site was definitely intended (as tours/help pages still show today) for programmers of a higher caliber/interest level. From Joel's 2008 announcement on the problems SO was intended to solve: "*And you won’t even get an expert answer. You’ll get a bunch of responses typed by other programmers like you. Some of the responses will be wrong, some will be right, some may be out of date, and it’s hard to imagine that with the cooperative spirit of the internet this is the best thing we programmers have come up with.*"

Comment: @TRiG Aside from that, you're letting some personal frustration muddle the waters here; OP is confused about the applicability of a particular close reason. Nothing was ever said about deleting content or some shadowy, scaremonger of a group such as "a cadre of deletionists"

Answer (score 44):

Not all questions about misunderstandings should be closed with this reason. But in many cases, reading the whole post-notice can better explain the close-reason used: *"While similar questions may be on-topic here, **this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers**."* (emphasis mine).

Questions based on a false premise are very often not useful for other users, because unless they have the exact same misconception they won't be searching for a solution for that problem.

Some *common* misconceptions are worth clearing up and leave documented, but even then taking care that the question remains useful, and trying to solve its X/Y nature (the poster is asking about X, but because of the original misconception the answer is about Y).

But more often than not, once the misconception is solved, there is no longer an interesting question to keep around. The question "*can no longer be reproduced*", because the misunderstanding no longer exists.

Comment: *Questions based on a false premise are very often not useful for other users, because unless they have the exact same misconception they won't be searching for a solution for that problem.* But the same argument can basically be applied to every question in the world? The point is not whether how many people need it, the point is *when* somebody needs it, they can find out.

Comment: Having the same problem is much more common than having the same misconception. The former happens all the time, and it's the reason a Q&A repository is useful. The latter is more unusual, because we can be mistaken in infinite ways about the exact same thing. It's the reason why many times questions based on a false-premise are rarely useful: they won't be found by users with the same issue, and they will be found by users having a different issue. Thus, they add noise and make harder finding really useful content.

Comment: what do you think about the suggestion/similar question feature? Do you think it's suffice? For example, my keywords are `regex`, `repetition`, `Notepad++`, `replace`? The answer turns out to contain only two of them: `regex` and `replace`. How can they be "mistaken in infinite ways about the exact same thing"?

Comment: I'm with Ooker on this, when you get to a certain level of expected research effort, and when you get to a certain level of expertise, every possible question is a misconception; you can encourage posting of "problems" but they aren't going to be high research effort problems, problem + research = "I tried this and that but it didn't result in Y", i.e., a misconception. Where do I vote on misconceptions? How many people have to have a misunderstanding before it's valuable? How long do we collect views on a question before we make that call?

Comment: How do we know that questions based on a false premise are rarely useful?  Do we just think so, or do we have data to support it?

Comment: "How long do we collect views on a question" apparently it's about a day; with that kind of sample size of views I think we're getting a bit too close to "Let's pull out our crystal balls and try and predict an audience" or, IMO worse, "I personally didn't find this confusing, therefore nobody would". Remember that the roomba is set up to clean out unpopular questions; personally I've found misunderstanding questions through Google and been okay with them, honestly, a weak clue is better than nothing.

Comment: @Ooker , you are chasing details on a completely non-existent issue.  (A) all of the close reasons are incredibly poorly written, (B) almost always the close reason is just something like "pretty low quality question, obvious mistake, too beginner level" and folks just try to pick one that is in some way close to that, and (C) few people put any much thought in to which button they pick on that screen.  More fundamentally new users and beginners are **just not welcome** on SO. SO-Snark is one of the basic facts on the net. Searching for detail is pointless.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's unfortunate that two close reasons got lumped together.  Often I see this one used for its second meaning:

1. Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced
2. or that was caused by a simple typographical error.

I can't say for sure that's what happened in your case, but it seems possible.

Comment: Why unfortunate? Why you can't say for sure? How would you vote?

Comment: @Sinatr it's unfortunate because those two reasons really have nothing to do with each other.  You're left to guess which one was relevant.

Comment: Wasn't this already discussed? To me both looks similar: it's a minor error, misconception, typo, etc. which once discovered invalidates and make the whole question useless.

Comment: @Sinatr there are many reasons a problem can't be reproduced beyond a typo.

Comment: @MarkRansom Right, and the overarching close reason is "no longer reproducible/not likely to help others". A typographical error is just one of the cases where that close reason applies.

Comment: I do agree the wording for the reason (and most of the reason) really sucks though.

Comment: @TylerH it's my belief that a close reason should give the questioner some hint of what they did wrong so they can do better next time.  This one fails at that because it's too ambiguous.

Comment: "give the questioner some hint of what they did wrong" -- they didn't do anything wrong. They had a misconception, which was solved, and now the question is no longer useful, presumably, to anyone. Getting your question closed doesn't mean you did something wrong, it just means that the question is not useful to SO as a repository of Q&As.

Comment: @CrisLuengo getting a question closed means you shouldn't have asked it in the first place.  That strikes me as "doing something wrong".  Knowing why would be a good thing I would think.

Comment: "it just means that the question is not useful to SO" That's like saying, if party B loses an election, "Party B is not useful".  As it happens, by consensus, basic/beginner questions are not welcome on SO.  But that's only as it happens and by consensus.  SO-Snark is a basic on the internet, it's utterly misguided to ignore that reality.

Answer (score -13):

To actually answer the two questions,

(1)

> why should it be closed, and

The simple observable reality is that, by consensus, basic/beginner questions are not welcome on SO.

(I don't know or care whether that is a good or bad thing; it's an observable reality.)

(2)

> why should it be the same with other "no longer reproducible" questions?

Close reasons are fatuous.  At the very best, noting point (1) above, folks just "quickly choose one that seems reasonably relevant".  More commonly folks just click the top one, or a random one, or the one that's already been clicked.

Comment: Check out the history of the "Too Localized" close reason, [it was deliberately killed off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154) to avoid people trying to predict the future. Personally I'd far rather have a (well written, non-dupe) question that "seems useless" stick around, I don't think it's a good idea to let a few close voters decide among themselves that nobody else would ever want to ask the same thing, but I guess some users want that? I've seen plenty of old questions closed as TL that had thousands of views. We're really bad at predicting the future, don't even try.

Comment: The reason it seems that beginner questions aren't welcome is because SO has been around long enough they are all answered. A simple Google finds the answer to most questions on SO itself.  Anyone asking a beginner question hasn't put any effort into finding the answer before asking.  I don't think SO was intended to be someone's personal Google service.

Comment: Total nonsense from top to bottom.